# adjust y-axis for missings in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

First some toy data:

```
df = read.table(text = 
              "id      year    value sex  
1           2000    0   1
1           2001    1   0
1           2002    0   1
1           2003    0   0
2           2000    0   0
2           2002    0   0
2           2003    1   0
3           2002    0  1  
4           2000    0   0
4           2001    0   1
4           2002    1   0
4           2003    0   1 ", sep = "", header = TRUE)
```

- When I want to visualize year by id for sex==1, I do

  ```
  df2 <- df[df$sex==1,]
  p <- ggplot(df2, aes(y=id))
  p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=year))
  p
  ```

  How can I hide observation 2 from the graph so that the distance between each remaining id's is the same? Is there a general way how to adjust the distance between two ticks on the y-axis when my breaks are id?
- Does the solution also works when using facets?

  ```
  p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=id))
  p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=year))
  p <- p + facet_grid(sex ~.)
  ```

Comment: This is rather unclear. Your first graph has only four points. If you remove two of them, how could they _not_ be the "same" distance apart?

Comment: Oh, that´s true. Sorry. I edited my question in order to be more precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited based on OP's clarification**

Create individual plots and use the **gridExtra** package.

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the use of **`reorder()`** should help.
Just to test it out, I changed the "id" value of 4 to be 7 in your toy dataframe.

To drop levels in individual plots, you can create 2 plots and then place them side by side.

```
    df2 <- df[df$sex==1,]
p1 <- ggplot(df2, aes(y=(reorder(id, id))))
p1 <- p1 + geom_point(aes(x=year))
p1


df3 <- df[df$sex==0,]
p2 <- ggplot(df3, aes(y=(reorder(id, id))))
p2 <- p2 + geom_point(aes(x=year))
```

If you notice, the id's without data are dropped. For example the following doesn't have id=2.
[image]

Now, you can use the gridExtra package which is meant for this purpose, to print out both the plots p1 and p2.

```
require(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p1, p2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

#### facet_grid() includes all levels by design

Using facet_grid directly won't work, but this is by design. Facet_grip has the `drop=TRUE` by default. Notice that you are not seeing id's=5 or 6. If an id appears in any one panel, it is included in all the other panels to facilitate comparison.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=reorder(id, id)))
p <- p + geom_point(aes(x=year))
p <- p + facet_grid(sex ~.)
p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Let me rephrase my question: From this graph I want to eliminate id =3 for sex = 0 and id=2 for sex =1, as there are no oberservations

Comment: `facet_grid` keeps the id's if they appear in any one slice. You can work around that by creating your own graphs of the slices, and then use gridExtra for the layout. Edited my answer to reflect that.